# Embedded linux launch python executable on startup

Tags: python, embedded-linux

I am trying to launch a python executable file generated using Pyinstaller on my target(a Beaglebone Black running Buildroot generated Linux). So far I have created a script file inside /etc/init.d directory named S03test with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

./../../test/test
```

And I have placed the executable at /test/test

When I try to run the executable using `./test` or using the script `/etc/init.d/S03test` by typing `sh /etc/init.d/S03test` I get the same error:
`line 1: syntax error: unexpected ")"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's a shell script, not a python script, so it should begin with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Don't use relative pathnames in init.d scripts -- the default working directory might not be what you expect.

Comment: If you execute `/test/test` by hand from the shell does it work?

Comment: No, it does not. It shows the same error. Also the other scripts in the init.d/ folder have the line ```#!/bin/sh``` at the start.

Comment: I just tried both your recommendations, still getting the same result. Isn't Pyinstaller supposed to compile all dependencies together for distribution?

Comment: Those recommendations weren't expected to fix this problem. What does `file /test/test` say

Comment: ```./S03test``` says ```File "/etc/init.d/./S03test", line 3 ./test/test SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` with a pointer pointer to the dot in "./test/test". ```./test``` says ```./test: line 1: syntax error: unexpected ")"```. I have changed the first line of the "S03test" file to "#!/usr/bin/python". I Still get the same results.

Comment: I asked for the output of `file /test/test`. Nothing about `S03test`

Comment: The file command does not exist in my Embedded linux. It says ```-sh: file: not found```

Comment: The file created by pyinstaller is supposed to be a standalone executable, and the init script's shebang should be `#!/bin/sh`. Did you generate the `test` executable on the beaglebone, or on your build machine? Did you generate it manually, or with buildroot? Pyinstaller doesn't cross-compile without extra magic. (Not sure if it can cross-compile at all) Also, you can copy the `test` file to your own machine, and run the file command there. The output of this command is independent from the system you run it on.

Comment: I just compiled the linux along with the file command and the output to ```file /test/test``` is ```test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=27cf7e8a1ee0edfa247b97aab240ca748648986, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped```. I generated the test executable on the build machine, manually. The output of file command on the build machine is the same except the build id sha1.

Comment: I have changed the shebang to ```#!/bin/sh```. I also read that there is a way to install python packages from pypi on the target machine. How is it done, most guides on the internet are for specific uses not generic ones

Comment: I suspect your target system is some ARM or RISC-V thingy, which would explain why your test executable, that is compiled for `x86-64`, is behaving weirdly. Installing packages directly on the target could be worth posting another question about it. (I'm not familiar with the buildroot ecosystem unfortunately, but others could pick it up)

Comment: You are right, the output to the ```arch``` command is ```armv7l```. Is there any way to instruct Pyinstaller or cxFreeze to compile for armv7l?